# Cocos2d different anchor points for one CCSprite

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have one `CCSprite` object. I start two actions. `CCRotateBy`, and `CCScaleTo`. I need to set different anchor points for these actions. How can i do that if `mySprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f,0);`changes the anchor point for both animations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your CCSprite as child of a CCNode. The CCNode will act as the additional anchorPoint.

Assuming you want to rotate the sprite around a center point in a circular motion, you would:

- offset the sprite from CCNode parent (radius)
- run the rotate action on the CCNode (sprite will rotate in circle around CCNode position)
- run scale action on CCSprite (adjust sprite's anchorPoint as needed)

Depending on what exactly you need the setup will be slightly different, and I'm guessing not all variations are possible.